# Align Navbar bottom-left

Tags: html, css, navbar

i'm working on this [website](http://n-restaurant.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/index.html) and as you can see i've a vertical left navigation. How can i move the navigations link left-bottom (only on desktop) like this?

[image: Bottom Left navigation]

```
<header class="span3">
            <div class="affix">
                <div class="navbar span3">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                            <i class="icon-reorder"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="brand span2" href="index.html">
                            <img alt="" src="img/logo.png">
                        </a>
                        <nav class="nav-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="nav-home active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-about"><a href="philosophie.html">Philosophie</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-services"><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-team"><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-reservation"><a href="reservation.html">Reservation und Öffnungszeiten</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-private"><a href="private-dining.html">Private Dining</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-kontakt"><a href="contact.html">Kontakt und Anreise</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
                 <!-- <aside class="span3 text-center hidden-phone">
                    <ul class="social inline">
                        <li><a class="btn btn-small" href="#"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a class="btn btn-small" href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a class="btn btn-small" href="#"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>        
                </aside> -->
            </div><!-- /affix -->
        </header>
```

Comment: you should use media queries for this, alike http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp but sounds to me you are using bootstrap here, so read the manual http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: why not use `position: absolute` and `bottom` props to position it on the bottom, for only desktop like `@media screen and (min-width: $desktop-width){ nav-bottom-props }`

Answer (score 1):

```
@media(min-width:1024px)
{
/* your style for desktop */
}
```